# Merging PHP Array and XML Object

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have an array like this, i am getting it by SQL query

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iId] => 1
            [sName] => Tom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iId] => 2
            [sName] => Jhon
        )
)
```

then by this array, i am creating POST request, and getting XML Object back

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [method] => userstats_xml
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [userstats] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                )

                            [test] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [output] => 1280
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                )

                            [test] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [output] => 6112
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And now i am trying to get array like listed below, because i can output data from first array and xml object separately, but i need to do it in one line, for example

```
<a href="sId">sName - volume</a>
```

In array form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iId] => 1
            [sName] => Tom
            [volume] => 6112
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iId] => 2
            [sName] => Jhon
            [volume] => 1280
        )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to parse XML manually, there's no way around it. Do you except us to write that parser for you?

Comment: i think this is quiet complicated to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the array and use the ID to query the XML with XPath to get the "output" value

```
foreach ($peopleArray as $i => $person) {
    $xpathQuery = sprintf('//type[@id="%s"]/test/output', $person['iID']);
    $result = $xml->xpath($xpathQuery);
    if (isset($result[0])) {
        $peopleArray[$i]['volume'] = (string) $result[0];
    }
}
```

The code will take each ID in your array and construct an XPath query from it. The query finds all output elements in the document which are children of a test element which has to be a child of a type element with the ID attribute from your SQL array. If a result is found, the value of the output element is added to the SQL array at the currently iterated position.

See http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html for a good XPath tutorial.

Comment: Thanks alot, modified your answer and got what i needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Iterate through the XML Response and build up a single dimension array with the iId as the key and the volume / output from xml as the value.

```
$xmlOutput = 
Array
( 
  [1] => 6112
  [2] = > 1280
)
```

Then you can use the above array to add a new element to the array you are getting from the SQL. Look at the code snippet below

```
 $sqlOutput =  
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [iId] => 1
                [sName] => Tom
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [iId] => 2
                [sName] => Jhon
            )
    )
    foreach($sqlOutput as $entry)
    {
      $entry['volume'] = $xmlOutput[$entry['iId']];
    }
```

Comment: @Gordon `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant iId - assumed 'iId'` ? Or in general, code is wrong.